# Magento 2 How to remove phone column in customer grid programmatically

Tags: magento2, grid, customer-grid, custom-column-grid

in customer grid there is a phone column like this:

[image]

i can filter this column or choose to hide/show this column from setting, i need to remove this phone column from grid and filter, is there a way to do this programmatically from custom module?

Comment: Check my answer will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml

You can remove by  `<item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>`

**Example:**

```
<column name="billing_telephone">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Phone</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

Run command:

> php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: it makes my grid wont load anymore, stuck in loading

Comment: @TinyDancer its working for me.